# How to download Google Photos pictures to Google Photos folder inside Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Previously (before updating to Google Backup and Sync app) I had been using Google Photos uploader app, and my workflow was as follows:

1. I had multiple picture folders (for example Pics1 and Pics2) on my PC to which I added new photos.
2. Then the Google Photos uploader app uploaded them to Google Photos.
3. Those photos then appeared in Google Photos folder in my Google Drive, all conveniently in one place and organized by year.
4. Then those photos synced to Google Photos folder inside of the Google Drive folder on my other PCs.

After updating to Google Backup and Sync, I set it up to pick up new photos from those picture folders (Pics1 and Pics2) and add them to Google Photos, just as before.

BUT: while they upload to Google Photos just fine, they no longer appear in the Google Photos folder inside of my Google Drive folder. That folder stopped updating with new photos. Instead, the new photos only appear in "My Laptop" section in Google Drive online website, with seemingly no way to sync it to my other PCs.

My question is, is there a way to make it work like before? I mean, to have all new photos upload to Google Photos AND have them downloaded to Google Photos folder in my Google Drive?